# mediapipe modifying face landmark subgraph problem

Tags: mediapipe, facial-landmark-alignment

I want to modify facemesh example and implement another face_landmark model. I've explored face_landmark module, in face_landmark_gpu subgraph there are some node that made me confused.
As far as I know, face_landmark_gpu is responsible for getting image and faces ROIs(obtained from face detection model) and putting landmark points on it.
in this subgraph, there is a node for spliting output vector of inference calculator to 2 vector. first for landmark tensor and second for **face_flag_tensor** . the next node Converts the **face_flag tensor** into a float that represents the **confidence**. what confidence mean here? I believe face detection is responsile for face presence not landmark model.

my model gives a tensor of landmark points as output and no other output for confidence or face presence score.
how can I use my model instead of default mediapipe ladmark?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: May be is late, but [there is a blog post](https://blog.gofynd.com/mediapipe-with-custom-tflite-model-d3ea0427b3c1) to use a custom tflite model.